# Как организовать версии коллекции библиотек?

Tags: github, библиотеки, gitlab, release-management, версионирование

Есть проект с несколькими связанными библиотеками. Как лучше всего организовать числа их версий, т.е. как должна версия проекта зависеть от версий библиотек? Например, для каждой библиотеки я использую классический [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) X.Y.Z. Когда, в таком случае, мне надо увеличивать версию всего проекта?

Answer (score 0):

> как должна версия проекта зависеть от версий библиотек?

Никак.

Но чтобы различать разные билды с одинаковыми исходниками проекта, но разными либами, можно делать Z+1, если было любое число изменений версий библиотек внутри

Но вообще это бессмысленно, и обычно всегда накапливаюся внутренние изменения и тогда инкремент от либ дополнительный можно не делать

Но в манифесте держать настолько подробную запись, как нужно и при необходимости показывать как-то так, как вот под рукой пример

```
TortoiseHg
version 6.2.3
with Mercurial-6.2.3, Python-3.9.12, PyQt-5.15.7, Qt-5.15.2
```